# How to mock and write Unit testing for Azure Service Bus Topic using Junit and Java?

Tags: java, azure, mockito, azureservicebus, junit5

I have a method to send and receive a messages from Azure service Bus Topic, I need to mock and write test cases for that method using Junit 5.

Sample code based on Microsoft documentation

```
    public class MyServiceBusTopicClient {

    static final Gson GSON = new Gson();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, ServiceBusException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TopicClient sendClient;
        String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<NameOfServiceBusNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<AccessKey>";
        sendClient = new TopicClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, "BasicTopic"));       
        sendMessagesAsync(sendClient).thenRunAsync(() -> sendClient.closeAsync());
    }

    static CompletableFuture<Void> sendMessagesAsync(TopicClient sendClient) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> data =
                GSON.fromJson(
                        "[" +
                                "{'name' = 'Einstein', 'firstName' = 'Albert'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Heisenberg', 'firstName' = 'Werner'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Curie', 'firstName' = 'Marie'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Hawking', 'firstName' = 'Steven'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Newton', 'firstName' = 'Isaac'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Bohr', 'firstName' = 'Niels'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Faraday', 'firstName' = 'Michael'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Galilei', 'firstName' = 'Galileo'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Kepler', 'firstName' = 'Johannes'}," +
                                "{'name' = 'Kopernikus', 'firstName' = 'Nikolaus'}" +
                                "]",
                        new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String, String>>>() {
                        }.getType());

        List<CompletableFuture> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            final String messageId = Integer.toString(i);
            Message message = new Message(GSON.toJson(data.get(i), Map.class).getBytes(UTF_8));
            message.setContentType("application/json");
            message.setLabel("Scientist");
            message.setMessageId(messageId);
            message.setTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(2));
            System.out.printf("Message sending: Id = %s\n", message.getMessageId());
            tasks.add(
                    sendClient.sendAsync(message).thenRunAsync(() -> {
                        System.out.printf("\tMessage acknowledged: Id = %s\n", message.getMessageId());
                    }));
        }
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[tasks.size()]));
    }
}
```

Method used to receive messages from the azure service bus subscription.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ConnectionStringBuilder;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MyServiceBusSubscriptionClient {
    static final Gson GSON = new Gson();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, ServiceBusException {
        String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<NameOfServiceBusNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<AccessKey>";
        
        SubscriptionClient subscription1Client = new SubscriptionClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, "BasicTopic/subscriptions/Subscription1"), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
        SubscriptionClient subscription2Client = new SubscriptionClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, "BasicTopic/subscriptions/Subscription2"), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
        SubscriptionClient subscription3Client = new SubscriptionClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, "BasicTopic/subscriptions/Subscription3"), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);        

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        registerMessageHandlerOnClient(subscription1Client, executorService);
        registerMessageHandlerOnClient(subscription2Client, executorService);
        registerMessageHandlerOnClient(subscription3Client, executorService);
    }
    
    static void registerMessageHandlerOnClient(SubscriptionClient receiveClient, ExecutorService executorService) throws Exception {
        // register the RegisterMessageHandler callback
        receiveClient.registerMessageHandler(
                new IMessageHandler() {
                    // callback invoked when the message handler loop has obtained a message
                    public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessage message) {
                        // receives message is passed to callback
                        if (message.getLabel() != null &&
                                message.getContentType() != null &&
                                message.getLabel().contentEquals("Scientist") &&
                                message.getContentType().contentEquals("application/json")) {

                            byte[] body = message.getBody();
                            Map scientist = GSON.fromJson(new String(body, UTF_8), Map.class);

                            System.out.printf(
                                    "\n\t\t\t\t%s Message received: \n\t\t\t\t\t\tMessageId = %s, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tSequenceNumber = %s, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tEnqueuedTimeUtc = %s," +
                                            "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tExpiresAtUtc = %s, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tContentType = \"%s\",  \n\t\t\t\t\t\tContent: [ firstName = %s, name = %s ]\n",
                                    receiveClient.getEntityPath(),
                                    message.getMessageId(),
                                    message.getSequenceNumber(),
                                    message.getEnqueuedTimeUtc(),
                                    message.getExpiresAtUtc(),
                                    message.getContentType(),
                                    scientist != null ? scientist.get("firstName") : "",
                                    scientist != null ? scientist.get("name") : "");
                        }
                        return receiveClient.completeAsync(message.getLockToken());
                    }

                    // callback invoked when the message handler has an exception to report
                    public void notifyException(Throwable throwable, ExceptionPhase exceptionPhase) {
                        System.out.printf(exceptionPhase + "-" + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                },
                // 1 concurrent call, messages are auto-completed, auto-renew duration
                new MessageHandlerOptions(1, false, Duration.ofMinutes(1)),
                executorService);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the exact implementation for mocking the above methods. It would be helpful If I get any documentation for the Implemenation.

Any one please advise on this ?

Answer (score 1):

For the sending messages code, you would want to mock (use a library like [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)) the `TopicClient` and validate calls to the `sendAsync` method.

For the receiving messages code, you could just test the `IMessageHandler`s directly, passing in constructed `Message` objects and mocking external dependencies if any.

Comment: Any links please?